# How to get the username that submitted a job in kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

Is there a way to find the username who submitted a job in kubernetes?

I've tried `kubectl describe jobs JOBNAME` and `kubectl get jobs JOBNAME`, but neither show the username who submitted the job.

Surprisingly, I'm not finding an answer to this question via google or SO search.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When creating objects in kubernetes, for example a `Job`, it is handled by the API server.
Even though the access is usually permitted only using authentication, this does not have to be the case. And even when authentication is used, it does not mean that something like a username is available. (Think of TLS client certificates)
Besides a `Job` can be the result of another kubernetes object, for example a `CronJob`, then there is no user creating the object, but kubernetes itself.

You can get the full dump of data of an object using YAML output, for example `kubectl get job sample -o yaml`, there is no username recorded.

You can record a username yourself, though, using the metadata (label or annotation).

Answer (score 1):

If it is a must for your case to find "who initiated the job" then you can set api server audit  - [https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/audit/][1]